# Android : how to make a complete image from its various part

Tags: android, image

I would like to show a picture (for example a house) from its various parts like its door, window, roof etc (different images of various part saved in asset folder). i am totally in dark from where and how to start to make this. If any idea or any library please help.

Comment: Are you asking how to overlay the images?

Answer (score 0):

you can load the images from resource on to a bitmap like so:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.place_drawable_name_here)
```

then use a custom view, on its onDraw method you can draw all you bitmaps one by one, the door,roof etc... so it will eventually look like a house.

```
public class MyCustomView extends View{
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ...
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

this is of course not a fully working code but it should give you pretty good idea of how you could implement what you wanted.